# URLDecode in dbsight in .ftl file

Tags: java, applet, freemarker, urldecode

Can any one have any clue how to decode the

> %E3%82%A2%E3%82%AF%E3%82%A8%E3%83%AA%E3%82%A2%E3%83%B3%E3%82%A8%E3%82%A4%E3%82%B8

value in `dbsight` in `.ftl` file. Its in java.

Comment: Not sure if you are asking for external URL decoding . It is here http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this

```
System.out.println(URLDecoder.decode(s, "UTF-8"));
```

Comment: This is equivalent of %D0%92%D0%B5%D0%BA+%D0%92%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%8F